# Is reusing a variable on c better than defining a new variable in terms of memory usage?

Tags: c, riscv

Hi I am programming in C and memory usage is very important in my project. So is reusing a variable on c better than defining a new variable in terms of memory usage?
My case is exactly like this: I have written a program and it has many layers (It is Convolutional Neural network in C), once the previous layer is done I go to next layer and some variables left unused. So can using them again in next layers will help me save memory or I am just sacrificing too much (for example in speed) and gain little memory?
For compiler I use https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain

Comment: Look at what the compiler outputs. Low-level optimizations like this require analysis of the generated code, purely looking at your higher level code will not tell you much, since compilers can perform a lot of optimizations

Comment: Never, ever reuse variables for other purposes. The current compilers are (or at least should be) smart enough to see which variables are left unused, and reuse the processor register or stack space for your new defined variables. -- Never, ever optimize prematurely! Only if your program does not meet your requirements, think about how to optimize. Variable reuse is not on any decent list, BTW. -- By reusing you sacrify readability and maintainability, and you as a human are not as reliable in detection as any compiler.

Comment: Anyway, limit your functions to one or two screen heights, and there will be no temptation to reuse variables. -- You can safely rely on the compiler's optimization capabilities for speed, memory needs, and code size. (Given that you use a decent current compiler.)

Comment: Once you leave the scope (layer as you say) the variables should be gone. Don't use global variables. Limit their scope to the functions where they are needed.

Comment: Measure, don't guess.  If you're bumping up against a hard memory limit, find out exactly where that's happening and limit any optimizations to that specific area.  Without seeing your code I can't really offer any helpful suggestions, but don't attempt any optimizations without first profiling your code to see where the actual bottlenecks are.  Don't do something hoping it *might* help - analyze your code and find out where it *will* help.

Answer (score 0):

As UnholySheep said in their comment, the easiest way to check for this would be A/B testing.

As a rule of thumb though, dynamic allocation is very slow, especially for big variables, if you're doing something like this:

```
void myfunc()
{
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {   
        uint128_t* myBigArray = malloc(1000*sizeof(uint128_t));
        doSomething(myBigArray);
        free(myBigArray);
    }
}
```

consider moving the array declaration out of the loop to something more like this:

```
void myfunc()
{
    uint128_t* myBigArray = malloc(1000*sizeof(uint128_t));
    
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {   
        doSomething(myBigArray);
    }
    
    free(myBigArray);
}
```

if you're not using any dynamic allocation, using something like that:

```
void myfunc()
{
    uint128_t myBigArray[1000];
    
    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {   
        doSomething(myBigArray);
    }
}
```

As far as I know there shouldn't be any difference

Comment: "there shouldn't be any difference" --> Stack overflow possible in last case.  Very unlikely in cases 1 & 2.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I meant a difference between having it inside the loop and outside. How would case 1 & 2 prevent an overflow?

Comment: You could (should) have checked if the returned pointer is NULL or not.

Comment: Tzig, Local variables are often stored on the stack.  Case 3 cost `sizeof myBigArray` (16000) is far larger than the single pointer size of `uint128_t*`, hence a greater chance of stack overflow.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I mean, you're technically right, but then case 3 is completely immune to heap overflows so it balances out? I think actually in case 3 the compiler should spit out an error if you try to allocate more than what you're allowed to (don't quote me on that though)

Comment: "case 3 is completely immune to heap overflows so it balances out?" No.  In case 1 & 2, code can check if that allocation succeeded and then perform other actions.  In case 3, code can "hope".  "the compiler should spit out an error if you try to allocate more than what you're allowed to" --> C does not require this, nor even detect the problem.  After stack overflow the behavior is undefined.